# Neo4j: Is there a fast way to get the distance between two nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes in a chain, like this:

```
(a)<-[:rel]-(b)<-[:rel]-(c) ... (x)
```

- Each node has a unique index.
- There are a few hundred thousand nodes in this chain.

Is there a fast way to count the number of nodes (or relationships) between `(a)` and `(x)`, **even if there are thousands of nodes between them**? So far `p=(a)<-[:rel*]-(x)` has been "slow".

*Note: I do not need to know anything about the nodes in between, I just want to find the distance.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the shortestPath method:

```
MATCH (martin:Person { name:"Martin Sheen" }),(oliver:Person { name:"Oliver Stone" }), 
p = shortestPath((martin)-[*..15]-(oliver))
RETURN length(p)
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-shortest-path